# General-purpose/generic test for container requirements compliance?

Tags: c++, stl, containers, std, requirements

Suppose you're writing a container, to meet the [C++ container requirements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Container). What should I do to make sure it's properly compliant? And Is it possible to have some general-purpose compliance "torture" test into which you plug any container's code and it passes compilation if and only if you actually meet the requirements?

PS - Let's assume C++14 or C++17, no C++20 and no concepts involved please.